# How to converter a list into a numpy array to use with the lib "face_recognition"

Tags: python, numpy

I’m using this module “face_recognition” and I’m using the function “face_encondings” to create a numpy array and save it on Sqlite3. But, when I select this face_enconding from sqlite3, it’s on string format. I’m needing some help to convert it in a numpy array to use the “compare_faces” function like this:

```
import sqlite3
con = sqlite3.connect("./teste.db")
cur = con.cursor()
import face_recognition
import numpy

j = face_recognition.load_image_file('mine.jpg')
je = face_recognition.face_encodings(j)[0]

cur.execute("SELECT faceencoding FROM users")
v = ''
for x in cur:
    v = str(x[0])

print(v)
j = numpy.asarray(str(v.replace('[','').replace(']', '')))
print(j)
result = face_recognition.compare_faces([je], j) #Here's where i'm getting the error!
```

The output erros is this:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/uriel/Documents/Python/fr/teste.py", line 18, in <module>
    result = face_recognition.compare_faces([je], j)
  File "C:\Users\uriel\Documents\Python\fr\myvenv\lib\site-packages\face_recognition\api.py", line 226, in compare_faces
    return list(face_distance(known_face_encodings, face_encoding_to_check) <= tolerance)
  File "C:\Users\uriel\Documents\Python\fr\myvenv\lib\site-packages\face_recognition\api.py", line 75, in face_distance
    return np.linalg.norm(face_encodings - face_to_compare, axis=1)
numpy.core._exceptions.UFuncTypeError: ufunc 'subtract' did not contain a loop with signature matching types (dtype('<U1555'), dtype('<U1555')) -> dtype('<U1555')
```

There was a moment that I could convert it but, also the array was empty ;s

Comment: Please reduce and enhance this into the expected [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Most of all, post the entire error message -- including the trace-back -- and trace the offending values with `print` statements.  Also check and correct your spelling.

Comment: Sorry! I've just made the changes!

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with the module you're using, but I think you might want to do `v += str(x[0])` instead of `v = str(x[0])`. As you have it set up at the moment, only the last value is being stored in `v`.

Comment: I'm using just 'v=str(x[0])' because in the database, I only have one register. The biggest trouble is just to convert it into a specific np array in a aceptable format to compare faces with the module.